# External Adapter repo throwing syntax error out of the box

Tags: chainlink

I'm looking to create my own external adapter. I pulled the [external adapter repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/external-adapters-js) and set it up with yarn per the README. However, when I try running `cd packages/sources/coingecko && yarn start` within any of the adapter directories, I get the following error:

```
/Users/jvilla/Documents/GitHub/external-adapters-js/packages/core/bootstrap/dist/lib/cache/index.js:73
        if (!context?.cache?.instance)
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.external_module_.Module._load (/Users/jvilla/Documents/GitHub/external-adapters-js/.pnp.cjs:42492:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jvilla/Documents/GitHub/external-adapters-js/packages/core/bootstrap/dist/index.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

The README mentions that some require environmental variables, but I don't see anything mentioned in `coingecko` and I'm not having any luck with the other adapters either.

Comment: Thanks for making this question! This is an issue that belongs better on the specific github repo rather than on StackOverflow. Thanks for being apart of the community.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help in the Discord, I was able to resolve my issue. I was using an old version of node and needed to upgrade! The separate, but related, [Chainlink Node Operator repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install) README has Node v12 hardcoded in its setup process, which won't work when running the External Adapter repo.